# how to cheked multiselect dropdown option?

Tags: php, json, ajax, codeigniter-2, multi-select

i have to multi select drop-down option 
and i have fetch result in ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type    : 'POST',
    data: {id:id},
    url     : url,
    dataType  : 'json',
    success: function(data){
        var len = data.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            var templatename1 = data[i]['templatename'];
            var fields = data[i]['fields'];
            $('#selectColumn1').val(fields);
        } 
    }
});
```

in  `var fields = data[i]['fields'];` response is like `a,b,c,d` (comma separated)

so how to select mached record in dropdown check box select like a,b,c options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $.ajax({
    type    : 'POST',
    data: {id:id},
    url     : url,
    dataType  : 'json',
    success: function(data){
        var len = data.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            var templatename1 = data[i]['templatename'];
              if(data[i]['fields']){ 
                 var fields = data[i]['fields'].split(","); // you have to convert comma seperated string into array
              }
              $('#selectColumn1').val(fields);
              $("#selectColumn1").multiselect("refresh"); // To refresh multiselect
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: if we use multiselect dropdown with checkbox than how to cheked dropdown option value?

Comment: Just update the answer

Comment: yes..its working..,thank you so much